# sort varchar column with alphanumeric data in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a column in redshift database which contains values like `11E, 11N, 11W,12W,12E,12S,1S,2E`. Need to sort column like `1S,2E,11E,11N,11W,12E,12S,12W.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to separate the numbers from the characters.

try this order

SELECT a FROM example
ORDER BY
convert(integer,case when length(a)= 2 then left(a,1) else left(a,2) end),
right(a,1)